# Video API trackface no response

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

i've been pulling my hair for a while because if this. i'm trying to implement the track face functionality of video api using the examples provided in the documentation [link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/565d6516778daf15800928d5/operations/565d6517778daf0978c45e39)

using the code:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/video/v1.0/trackface",
                        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","xxxxxx");
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: base64data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: 'application/octet-stream' 
                    })//end ajax
                    .done(function(data) {
                        console.log("GOT INTO .done !!!!");
                        console.log( data ); 
                    })//end done
                    .fail(function(data) {
                        alert(data['statusText']);
                    });//end fail
```

basically posing a blob object with the mp4 video. response code is 202 which means the request is accepted but processing time may be required. but i only get a null string as response.

if anyone has used this api. what is the response i should expect??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the response, there should be an "Operation-Location" header. You will use that URL to query the status with the Get Operation function

GET https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/video/v1.0/operations/{oid} HTTP/1.1